# Using ctx.guild.id is not working in a Discord.py cog. What should I do?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a discord.py bot and I’ve just expanded to cogs, but now when I run a command that needs to access `ctx.guild.id` but I'm getting an error assuming that I’m trying to get `cogname.guild.id`. What should I change to fix this?

I tried:

```
Class cogname(commands.cog):
  @commands.hybrid_command(name=“testcommand”)
  async def testcommand(ctx):
    ctx.send(data[ctx.guild.id])
```

I expected the json data for the guild to be sent, but I get an error saying that the class `mycog` doesn’t have an attribute `guild`. What should I do?

I'm using the latest version of everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`testcommand` is an instance method inside your class. In every instance method a parameter that refers to the instance of the class itself is passed. This is ideally named as 'self'

In your case its named 'ctx'. That's why it's referring to the instance of the class and gives you that error. Make sure you pass self before passing anything else in your function.

```py
@commands.hybrid_command(name=“testcommand”)
async def testcommand(self, ctx):
    await ctx.send(data[ctx.guild.id])
```

You can read more about instance methods [here](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/instance-method-in-python/amp/)

Also, ctx.send should be awaited!

Comment: if OP was using an IDE that showed `self` as highlighted, I believe this issue would've been avoided

Answer (score 0):

```
@commands.command()
 async def p(self, ctx):
       await ctx.send(ctx.author.id)
```

in ctx.author don't got any intelisense about ctx.author or any attribute under ctx also after invoking command it shows ctx does not have attribute author.id any solution please